# How do I write "ワンピースは実在する" vertically?

Tags: manga, handwriting, anime

I'm assuming there's certain punctuation involved in this sentence, but I don't really understand what changes in the process of switching from horizontal to vertical writing.

Comment: In vertical writing, the ー becomes ｜, and punctuation is right aligned. I can't think of anything else that changes but perhaps others will add to the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence has no punctuation. Only ー will flip to a vertical line, the rest stays the same.

Comment: What if i want it to be two vertical columns of text, where do i cut the sentence off? Is a row of "ワンピース" and one of "は実在する" correct?

Comment: @MarcoThePhoenix, broadly, yes -- that results in two columns of the same length, as ワンピース / は実在する, five characters each.  In terms of writing style, particles often remain attached to their preceding word, so in some ways that looks a little funny with the は starting the second column.  However, for the aesthetics of the visual balance, breaking after ワンピース works well.

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool here that could help you out:

> http://hinata.la.coocan.jp/tool/tategaki.cgi

[image]

Comment: This works for multiple lines as well.